# Can a array list of C# be used to populate SSIS object variable?

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis, etl

I have populated a list in C# script and assigned its value to SSIS object variable.

Then I used that object variable to execute some SQL query by looping through For each do enumerator.

I tried doing this by Foreach ado enumerator but getting error

> X variable doesn't contain a valid data object.

Can anybody provide any inputs.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your method where you set the variable value?

Comment: What enumerator do you use? 
Have you created a object variable that you map the array values to? How do you map the array item (in the loop) to the variable? 

Found this straightforward example: 
http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/18-Foreach-Loop-based-on-Variable-SSIS.html

Comment: I am populating LogList 

    List<vFailedTransactionNo> LogList = new List<vFailedTransactionNo>();
//populating List
 LogList.Add(new vFailedTransactionNo(Row.asutransectionnumber, Row.StageID, Row.EnrollmentID, "Cannot identify the Store ID,"));

 LogList.Add(new vFailedTransactionNo(Row.asutransectionnumber, Row.StageID, Row.EnrollmentID, "Cannot identify the Store ID,"));
//populating object variable vFailed TransactionNo
this.Variables.vFailedTransactionNo = LogList;

Comment: And used ado.net enumerator

Comment: Does setting the ssis vFailedTransactionNo work? Im not sure but usally when i set a value in a script task I do something like this:
Dts.Variables("SomeVariableName").Value = MyArray

Comment: Try to use the Foreach From Varialbe Enumerator instead

Comment: You should use Foreach From variable like holder comments

Comment: Well... a list is not an ADO recordset

Comment: Does variable enumerator will work fine with object variable?
as i always use ADO enumerator to loop through object variable.
New to this just wanted to confirm.thanks

Comment: @JaiAsnani Yes, except that you will run into problems if you have multiple values in your list.

Comment: @plaidDK: I do have multiple values in the list

Comment: @JaiAsnani Multiple values as in multiple columns or just rows? Look at my answer. It will solve all your problems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Youre using a list. Not a recordset and therefore you need to enumerate over a variable.

If you want to use ADO Recordset, you need to fill a datatable instead.

> 1. This shows you how to write to object with a variable list
> 2. This shows you how to write to object with recordset (using multiple values)

Like this:

**1 .C# Script code - Write to Object with list using variable enumerator**

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        List<string> NewList = new List<string>();

        NewList.Add("Ost");
        NewList.Add("Hest");

        Dts.Variables["User::NameList"].Value = NewList;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

**1. Variable settings in ssis**
[image]

**1. Foreach loop container settings**

> Use Foreach Variable Enumerator and use your object variable

[image]

> Map your outcome to a variable(s)

[image]

**1. Execute SQL Task test case**

> Write your SQL with variables

[image]

> Map your variable to Parameter mapping

[image]

**1. Result**

[image]

**2. C# Script code - Write to object with datatable using ADO enumerator**

```
   public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("FilmName",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ActorName",typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("Starwars", "Harrison ford");
        dt.Rows.Add("Pulp fiction", "Samuel Jackson");


        Dts.Variables["User::NameList"].Value = dt;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

**2. Variable settings in  ssis**

[image]

**2. Foreach loop container settings**

> Use Foreach ADO Enumerator and your object as variable

[image]

> Map your outcome to variable(s)

[image]

**2. Execute sql task test case**

> Write your SQL with variables

[image]

> Map your variable(s) to Parameter mapping

[image]

**2. Result**

[image]

Comment: nice explanation +1

Comment: @Hadi Thanks, i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @plaidDK
Second approch solved my problem

2.C# Script code - Write to object with datatable using ADO enumerator

Instead of list I have populated data table:

```
public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    //Get all the properties by using reflection   
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Setting column names as Property names  
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
    }
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {

            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

//Variable passed as below
Variables.vFailedTransactionNo = dt;

ANd then ado enumerator done rest of the job.

Thanks for help!