# How to save content of list into OBJECT type

Tags: ssis, script-component

I have a list/tuple which I have populated with some values. I want to save these values into a variable of OBJECT type in script component. How can I achieve this. Till now I did tried this with no success.

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private List<SomeValues> SomeList = new List<SomeValues>();
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
    }
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        //Object type variable in which I am trying to save list
        Variables.LatestDateTime = SomeList;
    }
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        var MatchingRow = SomeList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == Row.Id);
        if (MatchingRow == null)
        {
            SomeList.Add(new DateTimeValues
            {
                ID = Row.ID,
                LatestDateTime = Row.DateTime
            });
        }
        else
        {
            if (MatchingRow.LatestDateTime < Row.DateTime)
            {
                MatchingRow.LatestDateTime = Row.DateTime;
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeValues
    {   
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime LatestDateTime { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write your list to a datatable first and then set your datatable to your variable..

**Example - Fill datatable from list**

```
List<string> cities = new List<string>();
cities.Add("New York");
cities.Add("Mumbai");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof (string));
foreach (string str in cities)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["column1"] = str;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

**Write your dattable to your object variable**

```
Dts.Variables["User::NameList"].Value = dt;
```

And then you can use a foreach ado numerator to loop over your object variable in SSIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I don't know if I am allowed to ask the follow-up question in the same thread or not but how can we achieve vice-versa means Object to list

Comment: @Ashish Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099013/how-to-pass-a-list-of-custom-objects-in-a-ssis-script-task/48558602#48558602 - Here i write how to write an object to a list

Comment: And here you can see how i do some of the above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806837/can-a-array-list-of-c-sharp-be-used-to-populate-ssis-object-variable/47810464#47810464